# Smoothness of an algebraic curve in $\mathbb{CP}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

If $f=0$ is a curve on $\mathbb{CP}^n$ and at least on of its partials doesn't vanish at the point $P$, then it is smooth at the point $P$, which follows from the implicit function theorem. The reverse of this statement is false. Consider $f(x_0,x_1,x_2)=(x_0)^{3}$. All partials are zero but it is still smooth at the point $[0:1:1]$. Is it possible to make any constraints on the curve so that the reverse statement holds? I would guess that reducedness of $f$ suffices. Although I'm interested mainly in the case $n=2$ feel free to explain in any generality.

I had come up with this question while trying to show that $zy^2=x^3+zx^2$ is smooth everywhere except $[0:0:1]$. I know from the example above that vanishing partials doesn't imply non-smoothness.

Comment: There's something wrong in your question: $f=0$ defines a curve in $\mathbb P^n$ if and only if $n=2$, otherwise it is just a hypersurface. Moreover, $(x_0)^{n+1}$ is not smooth at all: all its points are singular as long as $n>0$.

Comment: There's a whole notion of reduced versus non-reduced scheme structure. The "double line" $y^2=0$ in $\Bbb CP^2$ is not the same algebraic variety as the underlying *set* $y=0$.

Comment: @Ferra Thanks, I was thinking about the case $n=2$. Fixed.

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree. But the topological data coincide for $y^2=0$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Well, there are several definitionss of what the "algebraic variety" defined by the equation is. The criterion you mention in the question only works when the equation of the curve is without repeated factors.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez My definition of reducedness is exactly having no repeated factors because that provides nilpotents in the structure sheaf. So you say that my criterion works?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Could you give a hint for the proof or is it something straightforward?